# Why does my function display only one output variable?

Tags: matlab

I am learning to use matlab. In the following code I want to apply the mldivide function https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html However, I am a little confused on how a function handles outputs. According to the documentation https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html when I call my function in the command window I should have out1, out2, and out3 spat out to me. But only out1 is displayed. Why?

```
function [out1, out2, out3] = testSystem(in1, in2, in3)

b = [in1; in2; in3];

A = [2, 1, 1; 
    -1, 1, -1;
    1,  2, 3;];

x = A\b;

disp(x);
out1 = x(1,1);
out2 = x(2,1);
out3 = x(3,1);

end
```

```
>> testSystem(2,3,-10)
     3
     1
    -5


ans =

     3
```

Comment: The page you linked has the right syntax, right under the heading "Function with Multiple Outputs" in the "Examples" section: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html#btexm36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you di not assign the output. Therefore, the function returns only the first output.
If you call `[out1, out2, out3] = testSystem(2,3,-10)`, it should do what you want.

Comment: I thought when I declared the out1, out2, out3 variables I was assigning the output. Thank you for telling me how to properly do this.

Comment: @Nalt To clarify: by defining the function as `function [out1, out2, out3] = testSystem(...)` you declare that it can produce three outputs. But to actually assign the three outputs to three variables you need to call the function with three outputs, like @shamalaia said.